# React-router.Problem with layouts,can't see other routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have 3 component LandingPageLayout,LoginLayout,UserLayout.I'm trying to navigate to the user/edit or any user related route from main page(landing) it leads me to 404 page,whilst others routes is okay.And my status isLoggedIn = true,basically logged in.

```
//main router
    <Fragment>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact render={props => <LandingPageLayout {...props}></LandingPageLayout>}></Route>
        <Route path='/login' exact render={props => <LoginLayout {...props}></LoginLayout>}></Route>
        <Route path='/offers' exact render={props => <RentOffersLayout {...props}></RentOffersLayout>}></Route>
        {isLoggedIn && <Route path='/user/id' exact render={props => <UserLayout {...props}></UserLayout>}></Route>}
        <Route component={PageNotFound}></Route>
      </Switch>
      <MobBtn></MobBtn>
    </Fragment>

//userlayout
    <>
      <Nav></Nav>
      <div className='profileWrapper'>
        <ProfileNav></ProfileNav>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path={`${match.url}`} component={Profile}></Route>
          <Route path={`${match.path}/edit`} component={EditProfile}></Route>
          <Route path={`${match.path}/saved`} component={Saved}></Route>
          <Route path={`${match.path}/for-sale`}></Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
      <Footer></Footer>
    </>
```

Comment: What happens when you navigate to `user/:id/edit` instead of `user/edit`

Comment: 1) yeah 2) <Route path={`${match.path}/id/edit`} component={EditProfile}></Route> like that?If so,I'm again at 404 page.All routes related to user leads to 404

Comment: Did you try remove exact from  user/id path Route?and maybe try match.path instead of match.url in the nested Route.

Comment: Removed exact still 404,match.url gives me route with dynamic user/17/edit Id, when path gives it's static,like user/id/edit

Comment: Have you seen the doc example? https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/nesting

Comment: yeah,I've checked this out,even when I make it static like path='/user' and link to='/user' won't help at all

Comment: remove all exact except from "/" route and "user/id" route. worked for me.

Comment: yep,looks like this is it,thanks a lot :*

Answer (score 1):

See following working example corresponding comments
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qu6hkq

Answer (score 0):

Change

`{isLoggedIn && <Route path='/user/id' exact render={props => <UserLayout {...props}></UserLayout>}></Route>}`

to

`{isLoggedIn && <Route path='/user/:id' exact render={props => <UserLayout {...props}></UserLayout>}></Route>}`

because `id` is a parameter for the route to use

you can read more here -> https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params

This is assuming you're actually passing a value as the `id` parameter to the URL